# Is it possible to receive donations via Amazon?

Tags: amazon

I'm creating a mobile app that I'd like to have the ability to receive donations to my Amazon account. Say, like $5 to my account to spend. Is this possible, and if so, could someone direct me to the information?

Answer (score 5):

Amazon accounts can receive Donations but there are a few caveats. [(Taken from this article)](https://payments.amazon.com/sdui/sdui/helpTab/Amazon-Simple-Pay/Integrating-with-Amazon-Simple-Pay/Amazon-Simple-Pay-Donations)

> **Who can use Amazon Simple Pay Donations?**
>
> Amazon Simple Pay
>   Donations can be used by U.S.-based,
>   IRS-certified 501(c)3 Non-Profit
>   Organizations to collect donations.
>   Follow a few quick and easy
>   instructions to set up your Amazon
>   Payments Business account with
>   Business type set to "Non Profit,
>   Political and Religion."

It is probably easier to use [PayPal to collect donations](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/xcl/rec/donate-intro-outside)

Answer (score 0):

You could ask people to buy you an Amazon gift certificate - you just need to provide them with your email address.

Answer (score 0):

There's no donations for individuals, but what most people (I've seen Marco Arment and Lifehacker do this) is join the [Affiliate Program](https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/) and ask people to buy something with the affiliate link.

The next Amazon choice would be to ask them to send a gift card to your email, but this reeks of amateurism and ticks people off.

[Flattr](http://flattr.com/)'s micropayment model has been going up pretty well lately. You may want to look into that as an option.